# InstallationError: Directory '/private/tmp/...' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found

Tags: homebrew, setup.py

I'm trying to make a brew formula work. It installs a python script with 2 dependencies on common libraries including psycopg2. The .tar.gz contains a working `setup.py`.

My .rb Formula is as follows:

```
class Asdf < Formula
  include Language::Python::Virtualenv

  homepage "https://my-homepage"
  url "https://github.com/asdf/asdf/raw/master/asdf-1.0.tar.gz"
  sha256 "a working sha"
  version "1.0"

  depends_on "python@2"
  depends_on "postgresql"

  bottle :unneeded

  resource "redacted"
       (etc)

  resource "psycopg2" do
    url "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c0/07/93573b97ed61b6fb907c8439bf58f09957564cf7c39612cef36c547e68c6/psycopg2-2.7.6.1.tar.gz"
    sha256 "27959abe64ca1fc6d8cd11a71a1f421d8287831a3262bd4cacd43bbf43cc3c82"
  end

  def install
    virtualenv_install_with_resources
  end

  test do
    system bin/"asdf", "--help"
  end
end
```

I get the log output:

```
==> Installing asdf from asdf/asdf
==> Downloading https://github.com/asdf/asdf/raw/master/asdf-1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/asdf/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/sha--asdf-1.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/37/db/sha/virtualenv-16.4.3.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/asdf/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/sha--virtualenv-16.4.3.tar.gz
==> python2 -c import setuptools... --no-user-cfg install --prefix=/private/tmp/asdf--homebrew-virtualenv-20190327-8864-er08i7/target --install-scripts=/private/tmp/asdf--homebrew-vi
==> python2 -s /private/tmp/asdf--homebrew-virtualenv-20190327-8864-er08i7/target/bin/virtualenv -p python2 /usr/local/Cellar/asdf/1.0.0/libexec
==> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c0/07/93573b97ed61b6fb907c8439bf58f09957564cf7c39612cef36c547e68c6/psycopg2-2.7.6.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/asdf/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/2e85a2e4c99e7531cc7b15f878ebfe254082386c495a470b63a9711a8bbdafec--psycopg2-2.7.6.1.tar.gz
==> /usr/local/Cellar/asdf/1.0.0/libexec/bin/pip install -v --no-deps --no-binary :all: --ignore-installed /private/tmp/asdf--psycopg2-20190327-8864-hnm0au/psycopg2-2.7.6.1
==> /usr/local/Cellar/asdf/1.0.0/libexec/bin/pip install -v --no-deps --no-binary :all: --ignore-installed /private/tmp/asdf-20190327-1234-1abce
Last 15 lines from /Users/asdf/Library/Logs/Homebrew/asdf/05.pip:
Created temporary directory: /private/tmp/pip-install-PAhyP8
Cleaning up...
Removed build tracker '/private/tmp/pip-req-tracker-JFqLxc'
Directory '/private/tmp/asdf-20190327-1234-1abcde' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/asdf/1.0/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 179, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/asdf/1.0/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 289, in run
    self.name, wheel_cache
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/asdf/1.0/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 269, in populate_requirement_set
    wheel_cache=wheel_cache
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/asdf/1.0/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/constructors.py", line 248, in install_req_from_line
    "nor 'pyproject.toml' found." % name
InstallationError: Directory '/private/tmp/asdf-20190327-1234-1abcde' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.

If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
https://github.com/asdf/asdf/issues
```

There's clearly a working `setup.py` file contained in the package. I can wget and inspect it.

```
$ wget https://github.com/asdf/asdf/raw/master/asdf-1.0.tar.gz
(etc etc)
$ tar -ztvf asdf-1.0.tar.gz 
-rwxr-xr-x  0 asdf    staff    5527 Mar 27 15:01 asdf.py
-rw-r--r--  0 asdf    staff    1825 Mar 27 14:07 README.md
-rw-r--r--  0 asdf    staff     505 Mar 27 15:07 setup.py
```

And I can't find other references to this error. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error was because homebrew expected all files including `setup.py` to be inside a subfolder called `asdf-1/` within the .tar.gz